# Android - Displaying the image in ImageView

Tags: android, image

I am new to Android, and I am trying to display an image taken by the camera. I am using an `ImageView` to do this. But when I run my app, the `ImageView` element just doesn't display. Here is my excerpt from `activity_main.xml`:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image_front"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
```

Here is the code in `Main_Activity.java` that changes the `src` attribute:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_front);

        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile(1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Error occurred when creating a file
                System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                img.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            }
        }
```

I am probably doing something wrong, so can anyone point out my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you "start an activity for result", your current activity is paused, and the new one (referenced by the intent) is started. Once it finishes whatever task it must perform, your previous activity is resumed, and the "onActivityResult" method is called.

On that method is where you have to load the picture and set it to your image view: (set photoFile as a instance variable of your activity)

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error occurred when creating a file
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

Then implement onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch(requestCode)
    {
    case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_front);
            img.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In call back from camera you need 
something like

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
switch(requestCode) {
case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
img.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
}
break;
}
}
```